How can I work on my custom theme on localhost when the site is live?
I have made my own custom theme on localhost, all working as intended, and then I put the site live, and all is working correctly. However, now if I want to carry on making progress on the site, I cannot, as the URL is pointing to the live site, and unless I change this to point back to my localhost URL, I cant access it. Obviously if I do this, the site will go down.
I could make a second database to work on, but then anything I put into the back end won't carry over, so I'll have to do all of this work twice. There must be an easier way? I know with Joomla you could have the back end linked to both, so you could work on localhost and change the code etc without changing the website or knocking it offline, and then put the code live.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
